# MacOS bash-file if-then doesn't work

Tags: bash, macos

He guys,
currently I'm writing a newbie-bashfile for work. The only purpose is to show/hide hidden files via one-click. My last script was ages ago and I researched for the right solution here and made up this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
 if defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 0
then 
 defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 1
else
 defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 0
fi
```

After this didn't work properly I tried

```
#!/bin/bash
 if defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 0
then 
 defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 1
elif defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 1
then
 defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 0
fi
```

Well - both work partly. So if the first argument is true (AppleShowAllFiles 0) it'll set the value to 1. But it doesn't work the other way around: The Else-condition doesn't do anything. If AppleShowallFiles 0 is false (meaning AppleShowAllFiles 1) it doesn't do a thing.
Why is that, what did I do wrong and how could I fix it?

I'd really appreciate any helpful answer and thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't fetching the current value of `AppleShowAllFiles`; you are setting its value to 0, and when that succeeds, you set it back to 1. Use

```
if [[ $(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles) = 0 ]]; then
    defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 1
else
    defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 0
fi
```